# Castor: Nesting elements

Tags: castor

Given the following domain object:

```
public class Domain {
   private String field1 = "one";
   private String field2 = "two";
}
```

how should the **mapping.xml** file be structured so the XML output looks like this:

```
<DomainObjects>
  <row field1="one">
      <field2>two</field2>
  </row>
<DomainObjects>
```

where "`DomainObjects`" is a static label.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlType("domain"), XmlRoot("domain")]
public class Domain {
    [XmlAttribute("field1")]
    public string field1 {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("field2")]
    public decimal field2 {get;set;}
```

Also you can get values

```
var result = from e in XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml").Descedants("Domain")
                  select new Domain{field1=e.Element("field1").Value,field2=e.Element("field2").Value};
```